# Possibility of optimizing an embedding function in embedding space.

Tags: parametric, nonlinear-optimization, machine-learning, mean-square-error

I have an optimization problem of the form: $$\text{minimize}_\theta:\mathbf{E}(f_\theta(y)-f_\theta(g(x)))^2$$ wherein $g$ is a known linear function, and $f$ is a nonlinear function parametrized by $\theta$. My question is whether or not this form of optimizing this objective via stochastic gradient descent is likely to degenerate. For example, if $g(x)=3x$, then $f(x)=0$ is a degenerate solution. I imagine some simple regularization should prevent this sort of degenerate behavior, but perhaps these edge cases are more numerous than they seem?

I know I could optimize this by arranging the objective as:
$$\text{minimize}_\theta:\mathbf{E}(y-f^{-1}_\theta(f_\theta(g(x))))^2$$ but I'm assuming $f_\theta$ isn't invertible. I'm sorry if any of this is trivial; I've simply never enountered problems of this form before, and don't know where else to look for answers.

Comment: I do not think this problem is clearly formulated.  It seems to have an expectation, yet, it is not clear to me what is random in this problem.  Are $x$ and $y$ decision variables, or random variables?  If $f$ is invertible, why is this optimization the same as taking inverse functions through the expectation? Why does the example $g(x)=3x$ lead to $f(x)=0$, and how does it constitute a "solution"? Is the dependence on $\theta$ a convex dependence, or not? I do not think anyone could help with your question without having these things clarified.

Comment: Thanks for the questions! I'm sorry the question isn't clearer -- I'm coming from a machine learning background, so I'm not confident I know the appropriate terminology to reach the larger optimization community. This is meant to be a regression program i.e. predict y given x. Except that I'm assuming that y is high dimensional and/or highly structured (e.g. image data) such that it might be easier to predict its embedding $$f_{\theta}(y)$$.

Comment: This could be problematic because changing the prediction, $$f_{\theta}(g(x))$$ also changes the regression target (they are both functions of theta). The question is basically, how problematic is it? Is collapsing all y to a single point the only degenerate solution? Is there a typical form of regularization people use in situations like this?

Comment: With regard to your last questions, I'm assuming this is a non-convex problem, as I'm hoping to use a neural network for the embedding function. And I'm claiming f(x) is *not* invertible. I'm just using the inverse to show how this problem relates to a more typical MSE regression problem. The example is a solution in the sense that the error will be 0 for any training set {X,Y}, since it simply mapping all points to 0.

Comment: Here is what I understand about your problem [some parts are still unclear]: I gather than $(X,Y)$ is a random vector with some (known? unknown?) joint distribution $P[(X,Y)\leq (x,y)]$.  We observe $X$ but we do not observe $Y$.  We want to estimate a function $f_{\theta}(Y)$.  It is not clear if $f_{\theta}$ are a given class of functions parameterized by $\theta$, or not.  Suppose we use a fixed $f_{\theta}$ function.  A classic optimization would choose an estimator $Z(X)$, it would not necessarily have the form $Z(X)=f_{\theta}(g(X))$, but you seem to restrict to that form.

Comment: I do not understand what the decision variables are.  Is it $\theta$, or is it $f_{\theta}$? Why does "$f(x)=0$" constitute a solution [where did $\theta$ go?  Why are we "allowed" to choose $f(x)=0$?  What if the all-zero function is not in the class of functions parameterized by $\theta$?] Is $g$ also a decision variable?  In the special case when $f_{\theta}$ is invertible, I still cannot understand your taking inverse functions through expectations.  What you get reduces to $E[(Y-g(X))^2]$ and you have no control over $X$ or $Y$ (perhaps no control over $g$) so this is not 0 as you claim.

Comment: Ah, I apologize for my loose terminology. $\theta$ is the parameter vector that parameterizes $f()$, which is what I mean when I say $f_{\theta}$. This $\theta$ vector is the decision variable we want to change during the optimization process. When I say that $f_{\theta}(x)=0$ is a solution, I mean that if some parameterization of $f$ resulted in that function, we would be at a global optima since the loss would be 0 for any {X,Y}.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48356/discussion-between-michael-and-zergylord).

Comment: The reason I'm using this terminology is because I'm trying to ignore the exact structure of $f$, apart from the fact that it is a differentiable function of $\theta$. For concreteness, we could assume $f_{\theta}(x)=tanh(tanh(x*\theta_1+b_1)*\theta_2+b_2)$ where $\theta$ :=$\{\theta_1,b_1,\theta_2,b_2\}$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the help -- bounty about to expire. Just put up a placeholder answer and its yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting a "placeholder" answer as per request, which summarizes the above comments and discussions.

I believe this is a situation where we have a random vector $(X,Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are possibly dependent.  The joint distribution may or may not be known. In the system under study, we can observe $X$ but not $Y$, and we want to build a good estimator for $Y$. According to standard theory, the best mean-square-error estimator is $E[Y|X]$, but we may want to do something else for various reasons.

Overall, we consider a class of functions $r(\theta) = E[h(\theta, W)]$ for some random variable $W$ that depends on either $X, Y$, or both, where $\theta$ is a vector and the function $h$ specifies some objective of interest. Likely we have some training data from which stochastic gradients of $r(\theta)$ can be computed.

The question wonders about "degenerate" cases when $r(\theta)=0$ for a particular choice of $\theta$.  I suspect that this issue is *essential* in the problem formulation stage.  That is, you want to choose the domain of $\theta$ carefully, along with the optimization metrics, so that your resulting $r(\cdot)$ function represents a meaningful thing to optimize. So, meaningful problems will likely avoid these "degenerate" cases.

However, once we agree on a specific $r$ function (typically a nonconvex function), the optimization procedure likely does not "care" about existence of cases that we would call "degenerate."  If you have some way of computing a stochastic gradient of $r(\theta)$, and if you assume $r(\theta)$ is smooth with Lipschitz continuous gradients, you can use a standard gradient method with a sufficiently small stepsize, where stepsize is chosen with respect to the Lipshitz parameter and the variance of the stochastic gradient.
Since the problem is nonconvex, you can only claim you are getting close to a point of near-zero derivative, not necessarily a global optimum.